# Get member offset in a template for glVertexAttribPointer

Tags: c++, opengl

Assume that I have my complete vertex data given in a struct `Vertex` in an array. In order to send the data to the vertex shader, I need to call the `glVertexAttribPointer` to set the correct mapping between `Vertex` members and the parameters of the shader.

I am trying to encapsulate an OpenGL function `glVertexAttribPointer` in a nice templated way.

`glVertexAttribPointer` serves as a kind of type description for a data upload from CPU to GPU, taking the following arguments as per [specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml):

- `GLUint index` - a handle
- `GLint size` - number of components (irrelevant for this problem)
- `GLenum type` - an enum value represeting a type (`GL_FLOAT`, `GL_SHORT`, etc...)
- `GLboolean normalized` - normalization to [0..1] or [-1..1] (irrelevant for this problem)
- `GLsizei stride` - byte difference between consecutive vertex elements. In my case that is the size of `Vertex`.
- `const GLvoid* pointer` - offset for the first element in relation to the beginning of the data. In my case, that will be the offset of the member in relation to the beginning of the `Vertex`.

To achieve my goal I have come up with the following solution:

```
template <typename WholeVertex, typename Element>
void attribute(GLuint shaderProgram, const char* name, Element WholeVertex::* memberPointer) {
    GLint handle = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, name);
    glVertexAttribPointer (
        handle,
        opengl_type<Element>::arity,
        opengl_type<Element>::type,
        GL_FALSE,
        sizeof(WholeVertex),
        (const GLvoid*)(memberPointer) //error
    );
}
```

where `opengl_type` is a my own trait class computing the correct GLenum value for a given type.

Unfortunately, this solution assumes that a member pointer is merely an integer offset and can be casted to `(const GLvoid*)`. To my knowledge, with an assumption that `WholeVertex` has a [standard layout](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_standard_layout/) that is true. Still, in generic case it may not be true and the compiler prohibits me to perfom this kind of cast. In fact, I cannot do anything with the `memberPointer` without having an object.

I found out that there is a [`offsetof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/offsetof/) function-like macro which could compute what I need, but the problem is it takes the member name as an argument, which makes it unusuable if the name is unknown.

So, do you have any other idea how this wrapper function could be implemented?
Maybe a different way of computing the offset? Or passing it as a different kind of parameter?

Comment: `Element WholeVertex::* memberPointer` actually confuses me, but I am guessing you are passing a pointer to a member of your structure.. if you know the address of the first element in your structure you can do some pointer arithmetic to compute the offset. You can easily do this without knowing the name of any member in your structure, but it will require storing an additional pointer somewhere.

Comment: The `attribute`, and ultimately `glVertexAttribPointer` does not work on actual data (thus I have no `this` pointer, or pointer to first element). These functions merely describe the `WholeVertex` type, letting the GL system know the offsets, before the actual data is provided.

Comment: @Andron: '..confuses me..' yes. it's a (offset) pointer to a member. one might pass in something like: `&MyVertex::nx` where `.nx` would be the start of the normal data members in some `struct MyVertex`. And as CygnusX1 points out; it has nothing to do with an instantiated object of type `MyVertex`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to get away from the constness of the member pointer.

You won't like this hack very much but it works:

```
template <typename WholeVertex, typename Element>
void attribute(GLuint shaderProgram, const char* name, Element WholeVertex::* memberPointer) 
{
    GLint handle = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, name);

    GLvoid *offset=0; 
    memcpy(&offset, &memberPointer, sizeof(GLvoid*));

    printf("ooook:%p\n",offset);

    glVertexAttribPointer (
        handle,
        opengl_type<Element>::arity,
        opengl_type<Element>::type,
        GL_FALSE,
        sizeof(WholeVertex),
        offset
    );
}
```

Perhaps a more preferable way using a union cast hack (still non compliant so maybe not to your liking either):

```
template <typename WholeVertex, typename Element>
void attribute(GLuint shaderProgram, const char* name, Element WholeVertex::* memberPointer) 
{
    GLint handle = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, name);

    union
    {
      Element WholeVertex::* x;
      GLvoid* y;
    }
    offset;

    offset.x=memberPointer;

    glVertexAttribPointer (
        handle,
        opengl_type<Element>::arity,
        opengl_type<Element>::type,
        GL_FALSE,
        sizeof(WholeVertex),
        offset.y
    );
}
```

&Finally, by [de-referencing](http://ideone.com/KRh6iJ) a pointer to null ( but still a hack :/ ):

```
GLvoid* offset=reinterpret_cast<GLvoid*>(&((static_cast<WholeVertex*>(NULL))->*memberPointer));
```

In defence of these hacks:

1. my understanding is that for a POD object, the current C++ standard ensures 
   the value of `memberPointer` will be a simple offset calculation.
2. `glVertexAttribPointer` is an API with hideous legacy of once upon a 
   time trying to mainatain backwards compatability. non-compliant means are acceptable.

Comment: All this relies dramatically on the fact that binary representation of member pointer is it's offset in bytes, which doesn't seen to be a good assumption.

Comment: @lisyarus : duh. the  `offsetof` macro *is itself* a hack that fails on non POD types. in any case read the OP more carefully..

Comment: downvotes grrr what a pain: 1) downvoter, if you are not lisyarus pls explain the rationale; 2) @lisyarus FTR, while your proposed answer is clearly absurd wrt your comments here and the OP requirements, it's still technically not incorrect. so i *did not* downvote you (just saying).

Comment: sorry, I was in hurry and didn't fully read both the question and your answer. I removed the downvote.

Comment: @CygnusX1 nb, since you appear to be making use of the C++11 `type_traits` you could also bung in [a compile-time check](http://ideone.com/ipeoxf) for a standard layout. just a thought.